# SettingsActivity with material design PreferenceCategory,SwitchPreference,etc in Android Kitkat

Tags: android, material-design, preferenceactivity

I'm trying to get material design look to SettingsActivity with PreferenceFragment, but unsuccessful. I'm on Android with version 4.4 (so Holo design) and I have settings with material actionbar, but everything else are in holo.

[image: Settings image]

This is my SettingsActivity

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {
private static Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener sBindPreferenceSummaryToValueListener = new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();
        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        return true;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setupActionBar();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
}

private void setupActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        Preference aboutVersion = findPreference("about_version");
        aboutVersion.setSummary(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);

        Preference forceCheck = findPreference("check_update_force");
        forceCheck.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                Check();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

preferences.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_general"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_general">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="exit_switch"
        android:summary="Show confirm dialog before exiting"
        android:title="Confirm exit" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_update"
    android:title="@string/pref_header_updates">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="check_update_start"
        android:summary="Check for newer version when launching app"
        android:title="Check for update at startup" />

    <Preference
        android:key="check_update_force"
        android:title="Check for new version" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
    android:title="About">
    <Preference
        android:summary="Jan Harčarik"
        android:title="Creator" />

    <Preference
        android:key="about_version"
        android:summary=""
        android:title="Version" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

Comment: Is it wise to force a particular look? It won't update then with any native gui in the future

Comment: I thought that AppCompat theme will set material theme for everything. In MainActivity material elements working without any problem.